# easy_install - pyCurl install issue

Tags: python, pip, easy-install, pycurl

I am trying to install pyCurl using easy_install, but I get the following error

`In file included from src/docstrings.c:4:`
`src/pycurl.h:170:13: fatal error: 'openssl/crypto.h' file not found
include <openssl/crypto.h>
1 error generated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1`

The `openssl` has been installed using `brew` and the version of it is `LibreSSL 2.2.7.` I have install xcode tools using `xcode-select --install` and does not seem to have fixed the issue.
I am also getting the same issue while installing using `pip`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This might fix your issue.

```
  $export PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl
  $export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
  $export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

Now you can easy_install or if you are using pip below should be the command.

```
$ pip install --no-cache-dir --compile --ignore-installed --install-option="--with-openssl" pycurl
```

Comment: This was the only thing that fixed this issue for me after upgrading to macOS High Sierra.

Comment: I am using macOS High Sierra. This works for me, too